# After updating to WKWebview not able to navigating next pages

Tags: ios, cordova, uiwebview, wkwebview, phonegap

After updating WKWebview in cordova project, it is not replaced UIWebview. That too i am not able to sign in or sign up or forgot password like. Please help me on that.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stackoverflow!
Please, extend your question with: 1. What have you already tried? Some code, errors, tutorial you tried etc. 2. 
Believe, we want to help, but quality answer requires a [good written question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: I followed this link.  https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-wkwebview-engine